# In C# how do I get a list of the keys from a dictionary?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
Dictionary <string, decimal> inventory;
// this is passed in as a parameter.  It is a map of name to price
// I want to get a list of the keys.
// I THOUGHT I could just do:

List<string> inventoryList = inventory.Keys.ToList();
```

But I get the following error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.KeyCollection'
>   does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method
>   'ToList' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.KeyCollection'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Am I missing a using directive?  Is there something other than

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

that I need?

EDIT

```
List < string> inventoryList = new List<string>(inventory.Keys);
```

works, but just got a comment regarding LINQ

Comment: yes, you also need `using System.Linq;`, because that's where the `.ToList()` extension method is defined

Comment: Don't include System.Linq; if you *only* need ToList() for this once instance, just call `new List<string>(inventory.Keys)`

Comment: And remember, an extension method can even be called like: `Enumerable.ToList(inventory.Keys)`, because ToList<T>() is `List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`, where the `this IEnumerable<TSource> source` can even be passed explicitly (useful in the debugger, when you don't have the using `System.Linq` definde)

Comment: @xanatos - `Enumerable` class is in `System.Linq` so namespace needs to be added anyways.

Comment: @RohitVats But at least the Visual Studio will suggest it :-)... You are right, the exact command is `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(inventory.Keys)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either use the [`Enumerable.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method, in which case you need to add the following:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Or you can use a [different constructor of `List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx), in which case you don't need a new `using` statement and can do this:

```
List<string> inventoryList = new List<string>(inventory.Keys);
```

Comment: Thanks - I used the new/different ctor - I did not need to and linq just for this.  I have to go back and see why i did not notice that in the docs - regarding linq inclusion

Answer (score 2):

`using System.Linq` is missing which contains `ToList()` extension method.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to loop through the Keys collection as in:

```
foreach (string key in inventory.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + inventory[key].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to explicitly make my own list.